# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0 JSF

Tags: java, jsf, hibernate

Tengo este codigo xhtml:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="input-group">
            <h:inputText p:placeholder="Nro Documento" class="form-control" value="#{BeanPersonal.paramNroDocSearch}" id="paramNroDoc" type="text"/>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="input-group">
            <h:commandLink id="searchButton" value="" >
                <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{BeanPersonal.buscarPersonasN()}" render="tablaDatos" execute="paramNroDoc"/>
                    <i class="fa fa-search fa-2x"></i>
                </h:commandLink>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
<h:panelGroup id="tablaDatos">
    <div class="row">
        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{BeanPersonal.personasN.isEmpty() eq false}">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <h:dataTable id="personasN" styleClass="table table-bordered" value="#{BeanPersonal.personasN}" var="perN" >      
                        <h:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">Apellido y Nombre</f:facet>
                            <h:outputText id="nombreCompleto" value="#{perN.nombreNCompleto}" />
                        </h:column>
                        <h:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">Nro. Documento</f:facet>
                            <h:outputText id="doc" value="#{perN.documentoNro}" />
                        </h:column>
                        <h:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">Sexo</f:facet>
                            <h:panelGroup rendered="#{perN.sexo eq 'M'}">
                                <h:outputText value="Masculino" />
                            </h:panelGroup>
                            <h:panelGroup rendered="#{perN.sexo eq 'F'}">
                                <h:outputText value="Femenino" />
                            </h:panelGroup>
                        </h:column>
                        <h:column> 
                            <h:commandButton class="btn btn-info" value="Seleccionar" type="button" >
                            <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{BeanPersonal.seleccionPersonaN(perN)}" render="datos" onevent="defaultTab"></f:ajax>
                            </h:commandButton>
                        </h:column>      
                    </h:dataTable>
                </div>
            </div>
        </h:panelGroup>
        <h:panelGroup >                 
            <h:panelGroup layout="block" rendered="#{Bean.personasN.isEmpty() eq true}">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-offset-3 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-12">
                        <h2>
                            <span class="label label-danger">No se ha encontrado la persona</span>
                        </h2>
                    </div>
                </div>  
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="input-group">
                        <h:commandButton class="btn btn-info" value="Dar de Alta Nuevo" type="button" >
                            <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{Bean.nuevaPersona()}" render="datos" onevent="defaultTab"/>
                        </h:commandButton>
                    </div>
                    </div>                      
            </h:panelGroup>
        </h:panelGroup>     
    </div>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Y en el BeanPersonal el siguiente metodo:

```
public void buscarPersonasN()
{
     personasN = new ArrayList<PersonasN>();
     Session sessionN = null;
     try{ 
         paramNroDocSearch = paramNroDocSearch.trim();
         sessionN = DBUtil.crearSesion();
         personasN = sessionN.createQuery("select p from PersonasN as p where p.documentoNro = :documentoNro")
                .setParameter("documentoNro", paramNroDocSearch) 
                .list();
         if(personasN == null){
             personasN = new ArrayList<PersonasN>();
         }
     }catch(Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
     }finally{
         if(sessionN != null)
             sessionN.close();
     }
 }
```

La idea básicamente es buscar una persona en una base de datos y agregarlas en una lista para poder mostrar en una h:datatable para que pueda ser seleccionada.

Cuando ejecuto el código, hay veces que funciona bien, pero otras en donde me larga el siguiente error:

```
Grave: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:635)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
at javax.faces.component.AttachedObjectListHolder.restoreState(AttachedObjectListHolder.java:166)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.restoreState(UIComponentBase.java:1604)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy$2.visit(FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.java:380)
at com.sun.faces.component.visit.FullVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(FullVisitContext.java:151)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1689)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.restoreView(FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.java:367)
at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.restoreView(StateManagerImpl.java:138)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(ViewHandlingStrategy.java:123)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:585)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.restoreView(MultiViewHandler.java:150)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.restoreView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:353)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:197)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:121)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Me da el error y no puedo encontrarle una lógica de porque lo larga, y no me muestra alguna linea del codigo de arriba.
El error lo genera cuando apreto el h:commandLink.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el alcance (scope) de tu bean? Asegúrate que por lo menos sea `@ViewScoped`. Asimismo, incluye la versión de JSF y CDI (si es que utilizas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema se debe posiblemente a "sessiones sucias" o "dirty sessions" en inglés, según lo informa [este tema de SOF en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12094077/jsf-session-fail-over-and-partial-state-saving).

```
at javax.faces.component.AttachedObjectListHolder.restoreState(AttachedObjectListHolder.java:166)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.restoreState(UIComponentBase.java:1604)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy$2.visit(FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.java:380)
```

Este problema ocurre generalmente cuando tienes por alguna razón cuando redespliegas la aplicación (comúnmente en tomcat). ¿Es posible que tengas más de una instancia de tomcat corriendo?

Podrías intentar también evitar guardar estados de respuestas parciales:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: Le agrege las lineas que me sugeriste al archivo web.xml y funcionó. Lo probé varias veces y anduvo, mejoró bastante. Muchas gracias.